# is there another way to display value from popupmenitem to Textfield

Tags: flutter

am working hard trying to get data from popupmenuitems and display on textfield this is what i have done, assuming that the productTypecontoller will hold the selected item value and show it in the textfield,but it did not do that.

```
 PopupMenuButton(
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
        return productType.map((String selectedType) {
          return CheckedPopupMenuItem(
              value: selectedType, child: Text(selectedType));
        }).toList();
      },
      onSelected: (value) {
        setState(() {
         
          productTypeController.text = value.toString();
          print(productTypeController);
        });
      },
      icon: Icon(
        Icons.list,
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: Where did you define productTypeController?

Comment: @Andrija its is a statefulWidget class hence in state i have defined this, TextEditingController productTypeController = TextEditingController();

Comment: Have you assigned the controller to the `TextField` with `controller:`? Besides, keep in mind that you should dispose controllers in an overridden `dispose` method of the stateful widget.

Comment: @PeterKoltai controller has been  assigned to textfield and it is disposed in dispose method,still the same problem, i have tested to print value to console : print(productTypeController.text); it print the correct selected value but ,the only proplem is to show it in textfield

Comment: thanks you all for your cooperation i have corrected my mistake and now it is working fine ,I actually forgotten the contoller in my custometextField.